# Nail Gun Recommendations - dado rail into brick/mortar

Tags: wood, nails, mdf

I've just finished fitting MDF dado rail to one of the rooms in my house, broadly speaking it all went ok with one hitch. I was using [these panel pins](https://www.screwfix.com/p/easyfix-sheradised-panel-pins-1-6-x-40mm-0-5kg-pack/12784) + a hammer, which were fine for the walls which were plasterboarded, but utterly useless for the walls which were brick/mortar. They bent repeatedly any time they hit anything remotely hard.

I have two other rooms to do, and I'm not looking forward to repeating the process purely because of the nail situation!

I had considered buying a nail gun, as a complete DIY'er it seems borderline ridiculous to spend more than £100 on one, but I'm just not sure which the right one for this particular job would be?

Are there any recommendations from the community which could help point me in the right direction from this selection: [Screwfix Nail Guns](https://www.screwfix.com/c/tools/nail-guns/cat830710?cm_sp=managedredirect-_-powertools-_-nailgun)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most nail guns aren't designed for brick, you'll be putting your self in risk of self harm either from jams or shrapnel when the brick gives way.

Getting a slightly smaller masonry drill bit and drill pilot holes that are fractionally smaller and nail in to those is a good option. Especially if you back it up with construction adhesive. The issue is that 1.6 mm is a very small nail, bits are hard to find.

Masonry nails are hardened, but usually larger so they need pre-drilling in the wood and a lot of finish work. but worth it if thats the look you want.